# accidentally deleted h2 settings. How to retrieve them?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

[image: h2 console]

I am not able to find Sqlite and some other settings on the console. I accidentally removed it.
How can I restore or add new settings?

Comment: Using a version control system like git? get it from there, perhaps you can recover deleted disk content, there may be [approaches](https://www.google.com/search?q=recover+file+linux+windows). Actually the question is considered off topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to restore the default settings, search for the file `.h2.server.properties` in the home directory of your user and either delete this file or replace its content with the following default (from the current version) and edit it as necessary:

```
0=Generic JNDI Data Source|javax.naming.InitialContext|java\:comp/env/jdbc/Test|sa
1=Generic Teradata|com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver|jdbc\:teradata\://whomooz/|
10=Generic DB2|com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver|jdbc\:db2\://localhost/test|
11=Generic Oracle|oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver|jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@localhost\:1521\:XE|sa
12=Generic MS SQL Server 2000|com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver|jdbc\:microsoft\:sqlserver\://localhost\:1433;DatabaseName\=sqlexpress|sa
13=Generic MS SQL Server 2005|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver|jdbc\:sqlserver\://localhost;DatabaseName\=test|sa
14=Generic PostgreSQL|org.postgresql.Driver|jdbc\:postgresql\:test|
15=Generic MySQL|com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver|jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/test|
16=Generic MariaDB|org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver|jdbc\:mariadb\://localhost\:3306/test|
17=Generic HSQLDB|org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver|jdbc\:hsqldb\:test;hsqldb.default_table_type\=cached|sa
18=Generic Derby (Server)|org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver|jdbc\:derby\://localhost\:1527/test;create\=true|sa
19=Generic Derby (Embedded)|org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver|jdbc\:derby\:test;create\=true|sa
2=Generic Snowflake|com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver|jdbc\:snowflake\://accountName.snowflakecomputing.com|
20=Generic H2 (Server)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:tcp\://localhost/~/test|sa
21=Generic H2 (Embedded)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:~/test|sa
3=Generic Redshift|com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver|jdbc\:redshift\://endpoint\:5439/database|
4=Generic Impala|org.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver|jdbc\:impala\://clustername\:21050/default|
5=Generic Hive 2|org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver|jdbc\:hive2\://clustername\:10000/default|
6=Generic Hive|org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver|jdbc\:hive\://clustername\:10000/default|
7=Generic Azure SQL|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver|jdbc\:sqlserver\://name.database.windows.net\:1433|
8=Generic Firebird Server|org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver|jdbc\:firebirdsql\:localhost\:c\:/temp/firebird/test|sysdba
9=Generic SQLite|org.sqlite.JDBC|jdbc\:sqlite\:test|sa
webAllowOthers=false
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```

You need to restart the H2 Console after it.

If you already have some own settings in this file, don't forget to copy them.

You can also add new settings from the Login form, it has a Save button for that purpose, just fill the form and use this button.

Answer (score 0):

path for .h2.server.properties is

Windows:

C:\Users.h2.server.properties

Linux și macOS:

/home//.h2.server.properties

Comment: C:\Users is not correct as different user has different path name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).